# RoR app: (Devise) seg fault after any route

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up the development environment for an internal RoR project.
Unfortunately there is no docu on this and the co-worker mainting this project is on vacation. (Quite a bad combo)

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.`name` FROM `roles` WHERE 1=0
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:236
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT `roles`.`name` FROM `roles` WHERE 1=0
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:236
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT `roles`.`name` FROM `roles` WHERE 1=0
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:236
  Navitem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `navitems`.* FROM `navitems` WHERE `navitems`.`url` = '/ideas' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/idea.rb:59
  Navitem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `navitems`.* FROM `navitems` WHERE `navitems`.`url` = '/contacts' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/contact.rb:44
  CACHE Navitem Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `navitems`.* FROM `navitems` WHERE `navitems`.`url` = '/contacts' LIMIT 1  [["url", "/contacts"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/contact.rb:44
  PageSearchIndex Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `page_search_indices`.* FROM `page_search_indices`
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:94
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/devise
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.slim (3.6ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/devise (21.0ms)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've had to set up `elasticsearch` and `yarn` for this to work.

The database has been created (`rake db:create`), the migration files were executed (`rake db:migrate`) and the initial data was seeded (`rake db:seed`).

But I'm currently running permanently in a segfault after executing any route on this development server (`rails s -e development -b 0.0.0.0`).

So I've already tried to break on all exceptions which occur during the runtime but no exception was thrown before and I just ran into the segfault again, which also makes sense.

Due to my C / C++ experience I do know how I would treat this problem on of these problems but regarding thsis rails app I'm quite overasked with this problem.

---

**I am not seeking for a copy & paste solution** which cannot exist due to the complex application setup **but** any **help which supports me troubleshooting this problem** in the context of this rails application.

Thanks for your help and support!

---

The Gemfile (maybe it helps):

```
ruby "2.5.3"
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "5.2.3"
gem "json"
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"
gem "seedbed"
gem "mysql2"
gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.1.0", require: false
gem "sassc-rails", "~> 2.1"
gem "coffee-rails"
gem "mini_racer", platforms: :ruby

gem "uglifier"
gem "rubyzip", ">= 1.0.0"

group :development do
  gem "pry"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "guard"
  gem "terminal-notifier-guard"
  gem "letter_opener_web"
  #  gem "quiet_assets"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "faker"
  gem "factory_bot"
  gem "rubocop-rails"
  gem "rubocop-performance"
  gem "dotenv-rails"
end

gem "simplecov", require: false, group: :test

group :development, :staging do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

gem "bootstrap"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "slim-rails"
gem "redcarpet"

# Still Master branch because of rails 5.2
gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", git: "https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git", tag: "v5.2.0.rc1"

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem "bcrypt-ruby", "~> 3.0.0"

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem "jbuilder"

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem "capistrano"
gem "capistrano-bundler"
gem "capistrano-rails"
gem "capistrano-rvm"
gem "capistrano-yarn"
# To use debugger
# gem "ruby-debug"

# auth
gem "devise"
gem "devise-i18n"
gem "cancancan"

gem "friendly_id"

gem "audited"

gem "ancestry"
# gem "aasm"

# gem "less-rails"

# switch to active storage
gem "image_processing"
gem "mini_magick"

# search
gem "elasticsearch-rails"
gem "elasticsearch-model"

# pagination
gem "kaminari"

gem "wicked"

gem "uuid"

gem "whenever"

gem "icalendar"


gem "paperclip"
gem "remotipart"
######################################
# admin
######################################
gem "rails_admin", "~> 1.0"

gem "ckeditor", "~> 4.2.4"

gem "active_storage_drag_and_drop"

gem "rails_admin_nestable", git: "https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_nestable.git"
gem "paper_trail"
gem "rails_admin_toggleable"

gem "font_awesome5_rails"
gem "select2-rails"

gem "webpacker", "~> 4.x"
```